# Prolog working with list and recursion

Tags: prolog

I am new in Prolog and trying to learn it. I came across a question and I am trying to run it but I think I am making a fundamental mistake and my code does not work properly.
I am trying to write a predicate that takes two arguments. The first argument is a list and the second argument is a list which members are the members of the first list, repeated twice.

Here is my code :

```
twice([],[]).
twice([X|Taila],[X,X|Tailb]) : twice(Taila,Tailb).
```

For example

```
twice([z,4,hello],X).
```

should return

```
X = [z,z,4,4,hello,hello]).
```

Comment: You have a typo. `:` should be `:-` in your second clause.

Comment: To find the error: Ask the most general query, like `twice(Xs, Ys).` And look what you get there.

Comment: You say your code 'does not work properly'. What _does_ it do? What do you get when asking `twice([z,4,hello],X).`? And if this is your exact code, as @aBathologist noted, you have a typo. Was that the problem?

Comment: Apart from the typo, your code works as it should.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer

```
twice([], []).
twice([X|Taila], [X, X|Tailb]) :- twice(Taila, Tailb).
```

Comment: ...which is exactly the code you had, but with the typo fixed.