# Prolog - Twice List

Tags: list, prolog, recursive-query

I am practicing prolog and all and this one is killing me. Trying to do this:

```
twice([1,2,3],X).
```

the output I want is

```
X = [1,1,2,2,3,3].
```

Here's my latest attempt:

```
twice([HD|TL],[HD2|TL2]):-
    twice(TL,[HD,HD2|TL2]).

twice([],[HD|TL]).
```

//New

```
twice([],[]).
twice([A|B],Out):- twice([A|B],[A,A|Rest],
                   twice(B,Rest).
```

Comment: twice of nothing is ...

Comment: the thing is that the problem says to use only list and recusive. No other advance Syntax.

Comment: Try to think of your predicates logically. @CapelliC is indicating that `twice([], [HD|TL]).` is a predicate saying that "Twice the empty list (nothing) is... what?" `[HD|TL]`? That wouldn't be logical.

Comment: Your newest code still isn't "logical". It says "twice `[A|B]` is `Out`" but then gives a definition that doesn't include `Out`. Think about: what should `Out` look like? Wouldn't it be a list with `A` repeated in the front of it? So the head of that clause should be `twice([A|B], [A,A|C])` ("twice `[A|B]` is a list that looks like `[A,A|C]` if...") and the body would complete the "if" by defining how `B` and `C` are related.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20319473/prolog-working-with-list-and-recursion

Comment: Ok so the problem was that i was reapiting then... Now i c were my error was... Thanx i shall practice now with the others. Thanx god im not taking the class yet >.<

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start with the base case,

```
twice([],
```

"twice of nothing is" ... *nothing*, right?

```
          []).
```

Now, what if there *is* something there?

```
twice([A|B],
```

then what? do we want the result to start from `A`? You bet,

```
              [A,
```

what next goes there?

```
                  ...
```

(fill it in, please). Then, there's the rest:

```
                       | Rest] ):-
```

so, we continue. The `Rest` is taken from `B`:

```
      twice(B, ...).
```

fill this in too, please.

Comment: I know how recursion works the part of the list is thats not fitting in for me. The Base case is ok. But the thing is I dont know what to do to add another data in the list of the same HD of the first list. Kinda confusing me... and i understood the above, but what im not seeing is the adding the same HD part 2 times.

Comment: @user3096350 you only have one thing to write instead of the `...` there, in the `[A, ... | Rest]` list specification. For example, `[1, 2 | [3,4]]` is another way to write down the `[1,2,3,4]` list. What if you want the 1 twice? Then it's `[1, 1 | [3,4]]`, same as `[1,1,3,4]`, same as `A=1, [A,A | B], B=[3,4]`.

Comment: @user3096350 you can edit your question, but don't change anything in it! you can add new code.

Comment: Allways gives me false :/ and its not Doing anything WHATS WRONG WITH U PROLOG!

Comment: @user3096350 paste your code somewhere, or add it here at the end of your question. there's the "edit" option under it.

Comment: @user3096350 can you just fill the dots in my code, please. It will be much easier. Copy, erase all text, line up the code, and fill the dots. :)

Comment: @WillNess: what a patience!

Comment: @CapelliC I got help from my friends :) in the comments, too. :)

Comment: @CapelliC (another good response would  be, "serenity now, insanity later!", heh heh :) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ow_9MglZrhs ).

Comment: @WillNess: nice, I'm unable to fully understand the gags (english spelling it's so hard...) but I get the mood

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at a simpler task first, a predicate where every element in input is not get to the output twice, but only once (input and output are the same, basically).

```
onlyonce([], []).
onlyonce([Head | Tail], [Head | NewTail]) :-
    onlyonce(Tail, NewTail).
```

The first clause is obvious.

The second clause means:

- the first argument (input) is a non-empty list. Name first element of that list "Head", name the rest elements of that list "Tail"
- the second argument is a non-empty list. The first element of that list is the same as in the first argument list "Head" (i.e. the first element of the input list *copied once*). Name the rest elements of the list "NewTail"
- "NewTail" can be obtained from "Tail" (and vice versa) using "onlyonce" predicate.

If you understand how "onlyonce" works, it's very easy to change it to "twice".

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
twice([], []).
twice([A|B], [A,A|Rest]) :- twice(B, Rest).
```